# Solution for issue in Redirect or RedirectModel in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have currently built a controller for my index page which is also a login page.

With the controller, I'm mapping the jsp if the login credentials of the user matches and if it doesn't I want to redirect to the index page with message "Sorry Username, Password error."

Here's the code:

**Controller**

```
if(uname.equals(inf.getUsername())&&pwd.equals(inf.getPassword())&&dept.equals(inf.getDept()))
        {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("uname",inf.getName());
            return new ModelAndView("employeeLoginResult", "message", message1); 

        }
        else if(uname.equals(inf2.getUsername())&&pwd.equals(inf2.getPassword())&&dept.equals(inf2.getDept()))
        {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("uname",inf2.getName());
            return new ModelAndView("adminLoginResult", "message", message2); 
        }
        else
        {

            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/index.jsp","message","Sorry");
        }
```

**The index page**

```
<b><span class="heading">LOGIN USER</span></b>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="login.html" method="Post">
            <div class="form_style">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username"/>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Enter password"/>
            <select name="dept">
                <option>IT</option>
                <option>Admin</option>
                <option>HR</option>
                <option>Marketing</option>
            </select>
            <input type="Submit" value="submit">
            <span class='disp'>${message}</span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The redirect works but the message get appended in the Url like this:
[image]

I just want to print "Sorry username password error" on the index file with ${message}

My question: 
Is it possible to use ModelAndView with RedirectView or if it isn't are there any other solution to send redirect to my index page with using ModelAndView?

Any suggestions or opinions are appreciated.
Thanks for the same.

Comment: have you looked at RedirectView with setting exposeModelAttributes as false ?

Comment: the problem with that is i'm only returning ModelAndView and can't use RedirectView. Could you share any code reference?

Comment: are u using xml based configuration? can you add `<mvc:annotation-driven ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect="true" />`

Comment: i'm already using <mvc: annotation-driven/>. I replaced it with your code but got an error:      Attribute 'ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect' is not allowed to appear in element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*The redirect works but the message get appended in the Url* " this is the expected behaviour of normal redirection attributes.

You can use flash attributes to redirect by not revealing the URL in the browser.

For example refer below code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String handle(Account account, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
   if (result.hasErrors()) {
     return "accounts/new";
   }
   // Save account ...
   redirectAttrs.addAttribute("id", account.getId()).addFlashAttribute("message", "Account created!");
   return "redirect:/accounts/{id}";
 }
```

Refer this : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html

Comment: can you share some code for reference? or any source?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a class like MyConfig

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
   @Autowired
   private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
     requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(true);
}
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to add @PostConstruct. It says that I manually need to make this annotation.

Comment: import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

Comment: Can I request you for a discussion as I seem to have a lot of questions and I can't seem to find a solution for the issue.

Comment: sorry what is a discussion in stackoverflow? were you able to try importing PostConstruct?

Comment: I imported javax.annotation.PostConstruct the issue with PostConstruct resolved but what is this supposed to do? Can you ellaborate?

Comment: requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(true) will ignore the model attributes when the redirect happens.

Comment: should i change <mvc: annotation-driven/> to the one you said above as the attributes are still being added in the URL.

Comment: The <mvc:annotation-driven ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect="true" /> in spring 4.0 is supposed to be like this <mvc:annotation-driven ignore-default-model-on-redirect="true" /> 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The issue is still prevelent. The attribute message is still being added in the URL